# Flutter: The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'

Tags: flutter

Getting this error with this:

```
return ListView(
  children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((index, DocumentSnapshot document) {
...
.toList()
  }
```

**Without `index,` everything works fine**

How would be possible to get an index here? Should I use a different loop to get it?

Comment: Try `toList().cast<Widget>()`

Comment: I posted a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used ListView.builder:

```
return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
```

Here the logic changes a bit and since I don't iterate over the list I need to assign it to a new var every time:

```
Map<String, dynamic> set = snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

Answer (score 1):

the children parameter of listView accepts a List as parameter your `snapshot.data!.docs.map((index, DocumentSnapshot document)` returns a `List<dynamic>` which is obvious because you haven't created widget list yet.

your method should be like this:

```
return ListView(
  children: snapshot.data!.map((value) => AnyWidget(value)).toList(),
);
```

**Edit**

I got your point. Assuming `index` is the index of list.

```
return ListView(
    children: snapshot.data!.map((document) {
      var index = snapshot.data!.indexOf(document);
      return Text('abc');
    }).toList()
);
```

better you convert `snapshot.data` into a `List<yourModel>` and use that instead of directly using it here.

Comment: I answered this already. I am returning a widget and everything is fine except for the index. If I remove it and I leave only (DocumentSnapshot document) everything works fine. The widget inside (which is huge and that's why I don't paste it completely) includes .toList()

Comment: Please check the answer now if it helps you. Let me know if you still face any problem.

Comment: thanks but I posted already a solution the other day

Answer (score 0):

i think it should be `return <Widget>`

Ex:

```
return ListView(
  children: data.map((dynamic value) {
    // Handle data
    ...

    // Return <Widget>
    return Text('$value');
  }).toList(),
);
```

Comment: I am returning a widget

Comment: Also that doesn't answer the question